# struts 2 : how to pass a global parameter from one action to another

Tags: struts2

I have a case like this:

JSP -> ACTION 1 -> Redirect-> Action 2 -> JSP

While redirecting we loose all the parameters. But there is one parameter that I'd like to pass from one action to another. The parameter is always the same for all actions.

I know that it is possible to write the following code and it works :

```
<action name="myAction" class="myActionClass" method="doThis">
    <result name="success" type="redirect">doThat.action?myParam=${myParam}</result>
</action>
```

The only thing is that I'd like to pass the parameter automatically from one action to another when I have a redirect without writing anything in my action tag, but I don't know how to code it.

Is it possible with struts 2 to do that?

Someone suggested to put it in global-results, I tried, but still haven't succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the property in to the session as an attribute and the same attribute can be taken back from the session irrespective of the action class you are using.
session.setAttribute(name,value);
session.getAttribute(name)

Comment: I just want to make my web application multitab. because the session is shared between the tabs, the parameter can be overridden. That's why I don't want to use the session